Correct routing for strap on Portland Design Works Origami rear fender
I have a Portland Design Works Origami rear fender. The strap that holds it on came loose while adjusting it and came completely out of the clip device. I have tried putting it back through in a few different ways, but no matter how I route it around the metal bar and plastic pieces of the clip, when I tighten down the clip onto the seatpost, the strap slips a bit and the fender becomes loose.
This is the piece that I am talking about:


I looked up the instructions that PDW publishes and the diagram is a bit abstract, as the strap approaches the metal bar at an impossible angle that would go through the metal bar itself:

From this picture, it would seem that it simply routes around the metal bar and back out, but this routing always immediately slips off for me.

Not having it in front of me I can't be sure, but have you tried putting it under the plastic bar (left foreground in you top pic), round the metal one, and back under the plastic one?

David D has the right answer. I have one of these. Here's a photo of it set up.

And here's a photo of it off the seatpost, showing the strap routing:


I had JUST figured it out finally and came back to add my own answer and found this! Thank you!! My mistake was thinking that one of the ends must route out of the front bit.
I will add that it is useful to route the loose strap back through the top bit of the buckle as it prevents it from rubbing on your leg.

Like Chris H said - it's hard without seeing it.
I've worked with something like this before - from memory....
The goal is to route the strap in such a way that the strap pinches against itself.
The metal bar will slide against the bar when pressure is applied to the strap.

So, if you route the strap under the plastic bar (into the slot marked in yellow.
Then around the metal bar
And back out the same slot the strap came in through.
Then when tension is applied to the strap the bar will slide toward the end of the clamp and pinch the straps.

I had JUST figured it out finally and came back to add my own answer and found this! Thank you!!
